# nginx uses built-in error page instead of my custom page

Tags: nginx, 503-error

My nginx server responds to not-found URLs as intended with my custom `404.html` file. I now want it to send my `503.html` when I set `$maintenance` to 1. But instead it sends its familiar built-in *503 Service Temporarily Unavailable*  | *nginx* error page.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name tarfu.example.com;
    root /var/www/v2/doc_root/web;
    if ($maintenance = 1) {
        return 503;
    }

    error_page 400 /error_pages/400.html;
    error_page 403 /error_pages/403.html;
    error_page 404 /error_pages/404.html;
    error_page 503 /error_pages/503.html;
    error_page 500 501 502 504 /error_pages/500.html;
    location ^~ /error_pages/ {
        root /var/www;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Q1: Why does this config make nginx use its built-in page instead of my `503.html` file when it reaches the `return 503`?

Q2: How can I change this config to get what I want?

Comment: One solution is to wrap the `if` block inside a `location /` block. Of course, this only works when there are no other `location` blocks in the `server` block, as in your minimal example.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, thanks! That does work. I guess this approach would mean seasoning all my `location` blocks with `if ($maintenance = 1) { return 503; }`. Doable if a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

##### A1

Per nginx' [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/): *The return directive applies only inside the topmost context it’s defined in.*

nginx' config directive reference says that `return`, which is in the [rewrite_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return), *Stops processing and returns the specified code to a client.*

My `return 503` is defined in the server context. It will therefore apply to every request nginx routes to that server. On serving the client's request it stops there and "rewites" it to a "request" for a 503. It uses the same search structures defined by my config and again hits the `return 503` without using the `location` context that provides the file path to my `503.html`. Unable to find my `503.html` it returns its own doc instead.

##### A2

Move the `if ($maintenance = 1) {return 503;}` inside a `location / {}` block child of the server block, as Richard Smith suggested in a comment.